# What is the best way to reduce such an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I suffer for a long time and do not understand how to filter such an array using the title and size

```
const items = [
    {title: 'pepperoni', size: 0, count: 1}
    {title: 'pepperoni', size: 1, count: 3}
    {title: 'pepperoni', size: 2, count: 1}
    {title: 'cheese', size: 0, count: 2}
]
```

Desired result has unique titles, summed counts and 0 size...

```
[
    {title: 'pepperoni', size: 0, count: 5}
    {title: 'cheese', size: 0, count: 0}
] // result that i need
```

I tried this:

```
items.filter(obj => obj.title === 'pepperoni' && obj.size === 0) // my last try
```

I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: I have no idea how your desired output relates to your dataset. Please further explain the criteria and visit [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `array.filter` is mean for filtering items out, not modifying them. Try [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), or just write a proper function.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking... You show that the result you need is `{title: 'cheese', size: 0}` but you are filtering for `'pepperoni'` and not `'cheese'`, so how do these things relate?

Comment: shouldn't the `size` of your desired output be `size: 3` for the title `'pepperoni'`? and `'cheese'` should have `count:2` as well. Your question is not very clear

Comment: I think the OP presumed that the solution would involve `filter()` because it produces a "smaller" array.  This confusion caused a more-negative-than-average reaction (in an already slightly ill-tempered culture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) invokes its block parameter for every element in the array, also passing the result of the prior iteration.

A common use of this is to reduce an array to one that contains unique elements, where uniqueness is determined by the block.

```
const items = [
    {title: 'pepperoni', size: 0, count: 1}
    {title: 'pepperoni', size: 1, count: 3}
    {title: 'pepperoni', size: 2, count: 1}
    {title: 'cheese', size: 0, count: 2}
];

// create an object whose keys are items' titles and values
// include the total count for each
const itemsByTitle = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let title = item.title; // by making it a key on acc, title will be unique
  // if it's not a key, make title a key, beginning with 0 count
  if (!acc[title]) acc[title] = { title, count: 0 };
  // increment the count for the title by the element's count
  acc[title].count += item.count; // for each matching title, add its count
  return acc; // return it, because this is passed to the next iteration
},{} /* see note */);

// note: since there's no "prior iteration" on the first iteration,
// this param tells reduce what to pass to begin
```

Now `itemsByTitle` will look like this:

```
{
  pepperoni: { title:'pepperoni', count: 5 },
  cheese: { title:'cheese', count: 2 }
}
```

and the OP's desired output will be given by `Object.values(itemsByTitle)`

Demo

```js
const items = [
  {title: 'pepperoni', size: 0, count: 1},
  {title: 'pepperoni', size: 1, count: 3},
  {title: 'pepperoni', size: 2, count: 1},
  {title: 'cheese', size: 0, count: 2}
];

const itemsByTitle = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let title = item.title;
  if (!acc[title]) acc[title] = { title, count: 0 };
  acc[title].count += item.count;
  return acc;
},{});

console.log(Object.values(itemsByTitle))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unclear about what do you want your items to be filtered by. The only common thing I can see in the items within your "result" array is that both items have a size of 0 so I assume that's what you are trying to filter by which is quite simple:

`const result = items.filter((item) => item.size === 0)`